# Distibuting desktop apache piviot application from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-pivot

I've developed a desktop application using Apache Pivot for the UI.

Everything runs fine when launched from Netbeans, but when I try to execute the .jar file on it's own I get the following error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at **********.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"131" Radix:10
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.pivot.util.Version.decode(Version.java:150)
    at org.apache.pivot.wtk.ApplicationContext.<clinit>(ApplicationContext.java:1697)
    ... 1 more
```

It seems like there are arguments Pivot isn't expecting, but this was run with the command;
`java -jar {filename}.jar`

The folowing enviroment;

- Windows 10
- Netbeans 8.2
- Java version "1.8.0_131"
- JDK "1.8.0_60"
- Apache Pivot 2.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known problem with the "Version" class in Pivot.  This was fixed very recently with version 2.0.5 (you are using the previous 2.0.4 version).  If you update your environment outside of NetBeans you should be good.  My suspicion is that NetBeans somehow gets the latest version but you don't have your class path pointing there outside of the IDE.

Comment: The weird thing is I added the libraries manually and linked them into my project before it would work at all. Thanks I'll grab the updated libs and see if that does the trick!

Comment: Let us know.  If you still have a problem with 2.0.5 you can file a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/PIVOT and we'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you! Updating to 2.0.5 fixed the issue

Comment: Awesome, that's what we like to hear.